# Unable to create "Analytics for Healthcare" App in CRM Analytics

Tags: tableau-crm, crm-analytics

So i was trying to create a new "Analytics for Healthcare" App from CRM Analytics which comes with the Dashboards and Datasets .
I ran into this issue while creating the app .
[image]

And when i checked the App logs it showed this
[image]

Iam not sure how to fix this.
I have been trying to find a solution and no luck.
Has anyone tried encountered this issue before ?
Its more like the dataset is failing to create or something.

Comment: Welcome to Salesforce Stack Exchange (SFSE)! Please do not post error text or code exclusively as screenshots - it is not as accessible to users who use screen readers or other assistive technology. (Plus it makes it harder for anyone to help if they want to copy any code and put it in a sandbox or code editor.) Instead, copy the error text and paste it in the SFSE editor with a greater than symbol (>) at the beginning to format it as a quote block. (Similarly, format any code with three backticks (```) above and below it in order to format it as a code block.)